# Can I bin data in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a lot of rows with dates in some SQLite database. I'd like to get some aggregated statistics for weeks or some other periods.

Is it possible to bin data in SQLite (i.e. get some number which corresponds to the number of the period - e.g. week)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a column of unique week identifiers use strftime('%Y%W', date_column).  More info [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

For your purposes I believe a "SELECT ... GROUP BY strftime('%Y%W', date_column)" should work.